# Create and run codeception tests from PHP

Tags: codeception

I know that Codeception is designed for command line usage. But as it is completely based on PHP, I am pretty sure there must be a way to dynamically/temporarily create a test by PHP.

In my case I am getting acceptance test steps from a database and need to run the tests dynamically with Codeception. I would prefer a way to test it without always having to generate and delete temporary test folders and running the codeception commands on the commandline.

The problem is that Codeception dynamically generates a bunch of config files and scripts when creating a cest. I couldn't make it work by using the Codeception classes.

Does anyone have an idea what's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds interesting. How are your test steps defined in the database? Can you show an example?

Comment: @Don'tPanic The complete structure is not yet done, it's more about the concept and the fact the tests should be created dynamically and not with static Cest files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best approach would be to implement custom test loader as documented at https://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Formats

You still have to use placeholder file in each suite to kickoff the loader, but the tests can be loaded from database.

Copy of documentation:

> In addition to the standard test formats (Cept, Cest, Unit, Gherkin)
>   you can implement your own format classes to customise your test
>   execution. Specify these in your suite configuration:
>
> ```
> formats:
>   - \My\Namespace\MyFormat
> ```
>
> Then define a class which implements the LoaderInterface
>
> ```
> namespace My\Namespace;
>
> class MyFormat implements \Codeception\Test\Loader\LoaderInterface
> {
>     protected $tests;
>
>     protected $settings;
>
>     public function __construct($settings = [])
>     {
>         //These are the suite settings
>         $this->settings = $settings;
>     }
>
>     public function loadTests($filename)
>     {
>         //Load file and create tests
>     }
>
>     public function getTests()
>     {
>         return $this->tests;
>     }
>
>     public function getPattern()
>     {
>         return '~Myformat\.php$~';
>     }
> }
> ```

Look at existing Loader classes for inspiration: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/tree/4.0/src/Codeception/Test/Loader

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is probably the best way to get it working using codeception. In the meantime I did a different approach by coding the test myself using Facebook's RemoteWebDriver library and selenium + chromedriver, which creates a virtual browser. This works pretty well now, although it needs the selenium java server to be running.